# disc failures, blk_update_request: I/O error

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl

I'm currently having a trouble accessing all recently installed discs on a server after a zfs pool rebuild. When I tried to partition using parted, I got the following error:
`Error: Input/output error during write`

Upon examining dmesg and smartctl, it seems like there's a problem with the discs. Is it possible that the discs were somehow damaged during the array rebuild? It seems quite unlikely that all of them got damaged at once.

smartctl tests are returning ok, but I cannot create a partition table.

Please let me know if you need more info

`dmesg`:

```
[   16.439672] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 8 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   16.439686] ata2: EH complete
[   16.686094] ata2.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x70000 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[   16.686103] ata2.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
[   16.686107] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   16.686110] ata2.00: cmd 60/08:80:10:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 4096 in
                        res 40/00:00:10:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[   16.686118] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[   16.686121] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   16.686123] ata2.00: cmd 60/10:88:28:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 8192 in
                        res 40/00:00:10:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[   16.686130] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[   16.686132] ata2.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[   16.686133] ata2.00: cmd 60/30:90:48:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 24576 in
                        res 40/00:00:10:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[   16.686139] ata2.00: status: { DRDY }
[   16.686142] ata2: hard resetting link
[   17.162142] ata2: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[   17.209854] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[   17.209865] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[   17.209867] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[   17.209869] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[   17.209871] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#16 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 08 00 00
[   17.209871] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 16 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[   17.209883] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#17 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[   17.209884] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#17 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[   17.209885] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#17 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[   17.209886] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#17 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 10 00 00
[   17.209887] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 40 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[   17.209890] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#18 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
[   17.209891] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#18 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[   17.209892] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#18 Add. Sense: Unaligned write command
[   17.209893] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#18 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 30 00 00
[   17.209893] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 72 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
```

`smartctl -a` output:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   87) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (1332) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   144   144   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       55
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   166   166   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       396 (Average 396)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       24
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   140   140   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       15
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       434
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       24
 22 Helium_Level            0x0023   100   100   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       123
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       123
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   166   166   000    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 25/37)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       138

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 138 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 138 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 428 hours (17 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 28 a0 00 00 00 40 08   1d+10:52:46.156  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 28 98 d8 ff ff 40 08   1d+10:52:46.156  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 01 12 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:46.148  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:46.148  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 13 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:46.147  READ LOG DMA EXT

Error 137 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 428 hours (17 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 28 18 00 00 00 40 08   1d+10:52:45.602  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 28 20 d8 ff ff 40 08   1d+10:52:45.602  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 01 12 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:45.601  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:45.600  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 13 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:45.599  READ LOG DMA EXT

Error 136 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 428 hours (17 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 28 a8 00 00 00 40 08   1d+10:52:45.070  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 28 a0 d8 ff ff 40 08   1d+10:52:45.069  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 01 12 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:45.068  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:45.068  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 13 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:45.066  READ LOG DMA EXT

Error 135 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 428 hours (17 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 28 68 00 00 00 40 08   1d+10:52:44.540  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 28 70 d8 ff ff 40 08   1d+10:52:44.539  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 01 12 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:44.538  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:44.538  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 13 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:44.530  READ LOG DMA EXT

Error 134 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 428 hours (17 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 43 00 00 00 00 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 28 58 00 00 00 40 08   1d+10:52:44.004  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 28 50 d8 ff ff 40 08   1d+10:52:44.003  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  47 00 01 12 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:44.002  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 00 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:44.002  READ LOG DMA EXT
  47 00 01 13 00 00 a0 08   1d+10:52:44.000  READ LOG DMA EXT

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       433         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       428         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Have you checked that the data cables are new/good?

Comment: Yes, this actually turned out to be a controller issue. Wasn't expecting another failure after the disc failure haha... Replacing it resolved the issue.